# How to Add more than one object contribution for Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Heloo,

I have a plugin with the plugin.xml file below,

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
        objectClass="org.eclipse.xxx.xxx.a"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.xxx.xxx.b" (ERROR !!)
        id="xxx">
     <menu
           label="NewMenu"
           path="additions"
           id="xxx">
        <separator
              name="group1">
        </separator>
     </menu>..... blah blah blah
```

My intention is to enable this "newmenu" for only two types of classes -

> org.eclipse.xxx.xxx.a & org.eclipse.xxx.xxx.b

When I tried to declare a new object class I get an error

> ERROR: Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type Attribute "objectClass" was
>   already specified for element "objectContribution".

How do I chieve my intention ??

Comment: In XML an element can not have the same attribute twice, but an element can contain more than one child element with the same name. In your case, you probably want to have two `<objectContribution>`s.

Comment: Things like this are why `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` was deprecated long ago and replaced with `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.

Comment: solved !! . Thanks @howlger